# Problem solving an equationsystem

Tags: equation-solving

The practice exercise I have tried is solve the equationsystem below.

```
ax + y + az = 2
x + ay + z = 2
x + az = 1
```

For what value "a" does the system have 1 solution? When does "a" have infinite solutions and for which "a"'s are there no solutions?

What i did so far was to use `Solve[{ax + y + az == 2, x + ay + z == 2, x + az == 1}, {x, y, z}]` for the answer `{{x -> 1 - az, y -> 2 - ax - az, z -> 1 - ay + az}}`.

From here on im not entierly sure how to continue to solve the questions in mathematica.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: @Moo so the answer would be that when a = 1 and a = 0. but when does it have infinite solutions and  no solutions?

Comment: There is a difference between `ax` and `a*x` or `a x` (noted the space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a solution could be as simple as helping Mathematica to realize that, for example, az is not a single variable but the product of a and z. One way of doing this is to leave a space between a and z:

```
Solve[{a x + y + a z == 2, x + a y + z == 2, x + a z == 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

This gives me:

```
{{x -> -(1/(-1 - a)), y -> 2/(1 + a), z -> 1/(1 + a)}}
```

Comment: Yes thats a good tip. Im still unsure how i can solve the a variable that the question is about. Got any tips for that?

Comment: @TehSwish you can specify a domain in Solve. I would expect the solution to fail if some terms containing a are not well defined. eg. a = -1

Comment: As Gladaed says, the domain is as wide as possible (e.g. all Complex numbers, of which Reals are a subset), subject to those values of a which result in values of x which are undefined, i.e. where the denominator equals zero. I don't believe that Mathematica can help you here.